# c# XML manipulation VB code conversion query... and more!

Tags: html, xml, linq, screen-scraping

I am following a VB tutorial to do some [HTML manipulation using LINQ](http://blogs.msdn.com/bethmassi/archive/2008/04/25/querying-html-with-linq-to-xml.aspx)

It has the following construct

```
Imports <xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
```

How do I do the same in C#?

There appears to be something called an XMLNamespaceManager that may hold the solution, but I am too foolish to understand how to work it, and I am not sure it is the correct tree to bark up.

Got any advice?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

VB.Net has a feature called `XML Literals` that is not present in C#.  This import statement adds a namespace for use with those literals.

In researching this information, I found this link helpful:
http://blogs.msdn.com/bethmassi/archive/2007/10/30/quickly-import-and-export-excel-data-with-linq-to-xml.aspx
It's also very informative for working with Excel xml docs, but that's a side issue ;)

Answer (score 1):

I think the example you're looking at may be using XML literals, which are not supported in C#.